# EXCEPTION: Unsupported operation: Platform._localHostname

Tags: dart, smtp, sendmail, mailer

I am new to angulardart and I am working on mailer, but I am having an error that says:

> dart_sdk.js:100398 
>   EXCEPTION: Unsupported operation:
>   Platform._localHostname STACKTRACE:  dart:sdk_internal
>   get localHostname package:mailer2/src/smtp/smtp_options.dart 4:25
>   new package:mailer2/src/smtp/helper_options.dart 12:24
>   new
>   package:DigitalHrSummit/src/components/homepagecomponent/homepage_component.dart
>   68:21            onSubmit
>   package:DigitalHrSummit/src/components/homepagecomponent/homepage_component.template.dart
>   1025:8  [_handle_click_287_0]
>   package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 602:29
>   src__core__linker__app_view_utils.appViewUtils.eventManager.zone.runGuarded.dart.fn
>   package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 134:16
>   parent.run.dart.fn dart:sdk_internal
>   run package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 131:18
>   [_run] dart:sdk_internal
>   runGuarded package:angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 302:22
>   runGuarded package:angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 601:37
>   event

Basically I just have the sample code that can be found [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/mailer2/latest/) . I have my gmail username and password in the options variable.

I have the sample code inside my .dart component(homepage_component.dart)

```
...
import 'package:mailer2/mailer.dart';
...
class HomeComponent(){
void onSubmit(Map<String, dynamic> contactUsInfo) {


    //Gmail account used to send email
      var options = new GmailSmtpOptions()
    ..username = 'my-gmail-account'
    ..password = 'my-gmail-password';




    // Create our email transport.
    var emailTransport = new SmtpTransport(options);

  // Create our mail/envelope.
  var envelope = new Envelope()
    ..from = 'sender-email-here'
    ..recipients.add('recievers-mail-here')
    //..bccRecipients.add('hidden@recipient.com')
    ..subject = 'Testing the Dart Mailer library'
    //..attachments.add(new Attachment(file: new File('path/to/file')))
    ..text = 'This is a cool email message. Whats up?'
    ..html = '<h1>Test</h1><p>Hey!</p>';

// Email it.
  emailTransport.send(envelope)
    .then((envelope) => print('Email sent!'))
    .catchError((e) => print('Error occurred: $e'));



  }
}
```

Please help me guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library [imports `dart:io`](https://github.com/tomyeh/mailer/blob/d8b85682667d97e30500a2ca94205341322325df/lib/mailer.dart#L3) and therefore it isn't usable on the web.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/2076 to add a warning at build time when a `dart:io` import shows up when building for the web.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I think i should find another way to send email with my web project. Thank you very much.